# map a letter as 0/1 values in an image layer

Tags: r, image

I want to map a character to 0/1 values of an image layer. For example, converting the letter "A" to a matrix of 0/1 that when it is printed it shows an "A". I came up with the following:

```
library(raster)
library(png) 

# write character to temp png file and read back in as matrix

letter_to_matrix <- function(chr="", size=10)
{
    tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")   
    png(tf, width = size, height=size)   # save as temp png file
      par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
      plot(0:1,0:1, type="n", frame=F, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="")
      text(.5,.5, chr, cex=1)
    dev.off()

    p <- png::readPNG(tf)     # read in png file as array
    apply(p, 1:2, mean)       # average over layers
}

 size = 10
 m <- letter_to_matrix("a", size)
 r <- raster::raster(nrows=size, ncols=size)
 raster::values(r) <- m
 raster::plot(r,  col=c(0,1), legend=F))
```

As you can see below for the letter "a" and "b" it is not really perfect. **I am looking for a better solution here.**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea, but you could use the Pixel font directly. For example "font.c" from the OpenGL SDK by SGI:

```r
charList <- list()
c(0x00, 0x00, 0x7d, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00) -> charList$a
c(0x00, 0x00, 0xfe, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0) -> charList$b
c(0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00) -> charList$c
apply(sapply(charList$a, intToBits)[1:12,1:12], c(1,2), as.integer) -> m
anticolockRotateMat <- function(x) apply(x,1,rev)
r <- raster::raster(nrows=12, ncols=12)
raster::values(r) <- (1-anticolockRotateMat(m))[,12:1]
raster::plot(r,  col=c(0,1), legend=F)
```

The full Hex code could be found in Open GL source code. You may use other pixel fonts too (if you get the hex code). There are plenty of 8-bit free font on line.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure if I understand it. So I would need the hex code list first? Is there an easy way to get it? Could you direct me to a site, where I can easily retrieve the HEX codes?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. For example, this code contains comments: http://www.computer-graphics.se/TSBK07-files/PDF10/mipmapcube3%20%2B%20simplefont/simplefont.c